# Delete everything after part of a string

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I have a string that is built out of three parts. The word I want the string to be (changes), a seperating part (doesn't change) and the last part which changes. I want to delete the seperating part and the ending part. The seperating part is " - " so what I'm wondering is if theres a way to delete everything after a certaint part of the string.

An example of this scenario would be if I wanted to turn this: "Stack Overflow - A place to ask stuff" into this: "Stack Overflow". Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For example, you could do:

```
String result = input.split("-")[0];
```

or

```
String result = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("-"));
```

(and add relevant error handling)

Comment: Do you know what if the primary string is like this : /name/nm1243456/lkbfwugbòwougs and I want to keep only nm123456? (I cannot use s.th like input.substring(6, directorImdbId.length() - 15) since the number of characters in the last part of string is changing (it might be 16 or 17 characters )

Answer (score 32):

The apache commons StringUtils provide a [substringBefore](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBefore%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method

`StringUtils.substringBefore("Stack Overflow - A place to ask stuff", " - ")`

Comment: This works really nicely. I'd expect most non-trivial projects to reference Apache Commons, and this avoids the error-prone fiddling with substrings/indexing

Answer (score 9):

### Kotlin Solution

Use the built-in Kotlin `substringBefore` function ([Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before.html)):

```
var string = "So much text - no - more"
string = string.substringBefore(" - ") // "So much text"
```

It also has an optional second param, which is the return value if the delimiter is not found. The default value is the original string

```
string.substringBefore(" - ", "fail")  // "So much text"
string.substringBefore(" -- ", "fail") // "fail"
string.substringBefore(" -- ")         // "So much text - no - more"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this

```
String mysourcestring = "developer is - development";
String substring = mysourcestring.substring(0,mysourcestring.indexOf("-"));
```

it would be written "developer is -"

Comment: Was looking for a solution to ignore everything in a string after a substring and your answer inspired me to come up with `String substr = mysourcestring.substring(0,mysourcestring.indexOf("searchSeq")+"searchSeq".length());` So for example if I need to ignore everything in a URL after a definite substring, this can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps thats what you are looking for:

```
String str="Stack Overflow - A place to ask stuff";

String newStr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("-"));
```

Comment: That *retains* everything after the matching string.

Answer (score 1):

I created Sample program for all the approches and `SubString` seems to be fastest one.

```
Using builder : 54
Using Split : 252
Using Substring  : 10
```

Below is the sample program code

```
            for (int count = 0; count < 1000; count++) {
        // For JIT
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    //Builder
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(
            "Stack Overflow - A place to ask stuff");
    builder.delete(builder.indexOf("-"), builder.length());
    System.out.println("Using builder : " + (System.nanoTime() - start)
            / 1000);
    start = System.nanoTime();
    //Split
    String string = "Stack Overflow - A place to ask stuff";
    string.split("-");
    System.out.println("Using Split : " + (System.nanoTime() - start)
            / 1000);
    //SubString
    start = System.nanoTime();
    String string1 = "Stack Overflow - A place to ask stuff";
    string1.substring(0, string1.indexOf("-"));
    System.out.println("Using Substring : " + (System.nanoTime() - start)
            / 1000);
    return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean way to safely remove until a string, and keep the searched part if token may or may not exist.

```
String input = "Stack Overflow - A place to ask stuff";
String token = " - ";
String result = input.contains(token)
  ? token + StringUtils.substringBefore(string, token)
  : input;
// Returns "Stack Overflow - "
```

> [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) functions are null-, empty-, and no match- safe

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need:

```
newValue = oldValue.substring(0, oldValue.indexOf("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = "deltaasm:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N        # line addred by agent";

    String rep = "deltaasm:";
    String after = "";

    String pre = ":N";
    String aft = "";
    String result = line.replaceAll(rep, after);
    String finalresult = result.replaceAll(pre, aft);
    System.out.println("Result***************" + finalresult);

    String str = "deltaasm:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N        # line addred by agent";

    String newStr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("#"));
    System.out.println("======" + newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can my utils method this action..

```
public static String makeTwoPart(String data, String cutAfterThisWord){
    String result = "";

    String val1 = data.substring(0, data.indexOf(cutAfterThisWord));

    String va12 = data.substring(val1.length(), data.length());

    String secondWord = va12.replace(cutAfterThisWord, "");

    Log.d("VAL_2", secondWord);

    String firstWord = data.replace(secondWord, "");

    Log.d("VAL_1", firstWord);

    result = firstWord + "\n" + secondWord;


    return result;
}`
```